# How to loop the drop down option elements?

Tags: java, selendroid

I am having a table which contains 3 columns.In the 3rd column i am having dropdown menu.I want to choose delete option.I need to loop the dropdown to delete the all element.So i tried to loop the element by using id Actions.I have tried to get the size and then defined loop.

```
List<WebElement> trlist = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy((By.id("Actions"))));
int l=trlist.size();
if(l!=0)
for(int i=0;i<=l;i++)
{

    //Select an option as Delete
        new Select(trlist)
                .selectByVisibleText("Delete");
}
```

But ,it shows the error while defining this  .selectByVisibleText("Delete");,because the selectByVisibleText as string it cann't be in List WebElements type.How can i loop and define the above delete drop down option?

[image: My table looks like below]

Comment: what if you click on this element? or try to use xpath.

Comment: No i can't use xpath .I want to loop the delete option alone.So that i can delete the all element easily.